# Namespace template functions and hidden namespace variables

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, private

I am writing a namespace that requires certain functions inside to have access to a particular variable (also declared within the namespace). Normally when I do this, I have the variable declared in the .cpp file to prevent outside access to it.

.h

```
namespace Example
{
    int myFunc();
}
```

.cpp

```
namespace Example
{
    int hiddenVar;

    int myFunc()
    {
        .. do something with hiddenVar
        return someValue;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I need to define a template function that requires access to this hidden variable. Unfortunately since the body of the template function must be defined in the header file it wont have access to the variable hidden in the .cpp.

.h

```
namespace Example
{
    template< typename T >
    void myFunc( const T& myT )
    {
         .. do something with hiddenVar  // doesnt know what hiddenVar is
    }
}
```

.cpp

```
namespace Example
{
    int hiddenVar;
}
```

Is there anyway to have a variable hidden within a namespace while giving a template function in the header access to it?

Answer (score 1):

.h:

```
namespace Example
{
  int * get_hiddenVar();  
  template< typename T >
  void myFunc( const T& myT )
  {
     int *  hiddenVarPtr = get_hiddenVar();
     .. do something with *hiddenVarPtr  
  }
}
```

.cpp

```
namespace Example
{
   int hiddenVar=0;
   int * get_hiddenVar()
   {
      return &hiddenVar;
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not prevent access to `hiddenVar`; anyone can call `get_hiddenVar()` and manipulate the variable directly.

Comment: @Gopric If you do not want to do write permission to hiddenVar, then change return value of function to "const int *". No problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly, but you can use a function. Since `hiddenVar` does not depend on the template parameters, you can do this:

.h

```
namespace Example
{
  void Function(); // Use the right function prototype here, of course,
                   // as long as it does not depend on T

  template<typename T>
  void myFunc(const T& myT)
  {
    //...
    Function();
    //...
  }
}
```

.cpp

```
namespace Example
{
  int hiddenVar;
  void Function()
  {
    // Do something with hiddenVar
  }
}
```

If your use of `hiddenVar` depends on `T`, of course, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a nested namespace called 'Details' and stop worrying.

'Hiding' a variable using namespaces and private etc are not security-constructs, but there to facilitate better code.